# C# Multiple Parameter From Single Expression

Tags: c#, entity-framework, linq, lambda

Do any one know how to send multiple parameter from single expression.

Please refer to my below class;

```
public class EMP 
{
    public string NAME { get; set; }
    public String FULLNAME { get; set; }
}
```

I would like to send selective property to a function, something like below.

```
SendColumn<EMP>(a=>{cl.NAME,cl.FULLNAME})
```

or

```
SendColumn<EMP>(cl =>cl.NAME,cl.FULLNAME)
```

Right now using the below function, I can only send one parameter per expression

```
public List<TRow> SendColumn<TValue>(Func<TRow, TValue> expression )
{
    // do some processing
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Try using this syntax:

```
SendColumn(e => new EMP { NAME = "testName", FULLNAME = "TestFullName" });
```

If that doesn't work, please elaborate on your context and what error you are getting.

Comment: Can you give some explanation about your answer? For me It probably won't work.

Comment: @LeonelSarmiento - The OP hasn't given enough information to get more information than this I think.

Comment: @Leonel Sarmiento - You are right. I edited my answer to use the type which was likely intended by OP rather than an anonymous type.